# Returning string matches between two lists for a given number of elements in a third list

Tags: python, list, set-intersection

I've got a feeling that I will be told to go to the 'beginner's guide' or what have you but I have this code here that goes

```
does = ['my','mother','told','me','to','choose','the']
it = ['my','mother','told','me','to','choose','the']
work = []

while 5 > len(work):
    for nope in it:
        if nope in does:
            work.append(nope)

print (work)
```

And I get

```
['my', 'mother', 'told', 'me', 'to', 'choose', 'the']
```

Why is this? And how do I convince it to return

```
['my', 'mother', 'told', 'me']
```

Comment: This is like a set intersection (truncated), although sets don't have order.

Comment: Note that using the order `while 5>len(work)` is seen illogical by many, leading to the name of ["yoda conditions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). It's correct either way of course:)

Comment: @WilliamCorrigan You should accept the answer you found helpful to indicate to other readers what helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like this:

```
for nope in it:
   if len(work) < 5 and nope in does:
       work.append(nope)
   else:
       break
```

The problem with your code is that it does the check of the work's length, after having looped through all the items of `it` and having added all of them that are in `does`.

Comment: More optimal and clearer than my solution. I deleted mine to make sure yours was clearly seen as the favoured solution. +1

Comment: @idjaw thank you very much ! It wasn't needed to delete your answer :)

Comment: For this case, I liked your solution much more than mine and hope the OP sees the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
does = ['my','mother','told','me','to','choose','the']
it = ['my','mother','told','me','to','choose','the']
work = []
for nope in it:
    if nope in does:
        work.append(nope)
work = work[:4]
print (work)
```

It's just making the list without checking the length, then cutting it and leaving only the 4 first elements.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, to stay a little closer to your original logic:

```
i = 0
while 4 > len(work) and i < len(it):
    nope = it[i]
    if nope in does:
        work.append(nope)
    i += 1

# ['my', 'mother', 'told', 'me', 'to']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a one-liner with no imports:

```
does = ['my', 'mother', 'told', 'me', 'to', 'choose', 'the']
it = ['my', 'mother', 'told', 'me', 'to', 'choose', 'the']
work = [match for match, _ in zip((nope for nope in does if nope in it), range(4))]
```